# Log response from webservice

Tags: java, jboss, jax-ws, jbossws

I am using Jboss and jax-ws.

How can I gent a similar effect to the

```
System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump", "true")?
```

Thank you!
Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look to enable the httpclient.wire.content category in the JBoss logging, this will dump the http messages into the configured log file.

```
  <category name="httpclient.wire.content">
      <priority value="DEBUG"/>
   </category>
```

You add this to the `<YOUR JBOSS INSTALL FOLDER>\server\default\conf\jboss-log4j.xml` within the `</log4j:configuration>` tag

Comment: i'm a beginner - so, could you be more detailed? - in which file to add the above element? Thank you!

Comment: @Roxana just to add some info, instead of `default` folder in `<YOUR JBOSS INSTALL FOLDER>\server`, you should go to your actual server folder. Generally, `default` is your server folder for development and testing operations, but for production you should create another folder with the production configurations, as is recommended in [JBoss AS Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/jboss4guide/r1/html/ch01.html#ch1.dirs.fig)